# ANT exec translate from windows to unix

Tags: linux, windows, maven, ant, sh

I used to have windows as my dev machine but now i have moved to linux and i am facing few problems here and there. At the moment i am having problems with my ant script which on windows used to execute my pom file automatically. But now it does not do it ;)

```
<target name="execute-pom" description="Execute orderlystatsse.pom file" depends="copy-properties">
        <exec dir="." executable="cmd"> 
            <arg line="/c mvn -T 4C install -Dmaven.test.skip=true" />
        </exec>
    </target>
```

Thats the script in question. As of now its complaining that `cmd` is not recognized `/c` is not recognized etc. How would i translate this to work with linux?

Comment: Why don't you call `mvn -T 4C install -Dmaven.test.skip=true` ? I don't understand why you are using an Ant script?

Comment: @khmarbaise because i use the script to do this automatically everytime i save file which i have edited ;). It just saves time for me

Comment: why have ant call maven? why not call mvn directly?  Your answer to @khmarbaise question doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

Actually i have found answer few minutes after posting this ;).

The way i solved it was :

```
<target name="execute-pom" description="Execute orderlystats.pom file" depends="copy-properties">
    <exec dir="." executable="sudo"> 
        <arg line="-S mvn -T 4C install -Dmaven.test.skip=true" />
    </exec> 
</target>
```

Comment: This is a terrible plan. You shouldn't be running your build as root.

Comment: @thekbb any particular reason why ?. build is fully controller process. Do you have another solution that will work ;) ?

Comment: Generally you need a reason TO run something as root.  Badness could happen - a bug or maliciously written script could be bad.  that and the output of the build will be owned by root - your user won't be able to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those questions I'm hesitant to answer, as I think the real answer is to not do what you're trying to do.

It's failing because `cmd` only exists on windows.

The quickest way to get this working would be to change `executable` to `mvn`  (You may have to specify the location of `mvn` in a property if it's not on your PATH).

It would be better yet to use the [maven ant tasks](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/examples/mvn.html).  I admit I've never used them - it seems like a solution begging for a problem.

The best plan is to not have an ant script that wraps up your maven build.